# Confused about Web share API and Cordova share plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-chrome, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to implement a share feature in my Cordova app to let users share their pictures

According to the Chrome dev team they introduced a [Web share API](https://github.com/WICG/web-share) directly into Google Chrome. To share something just call:

```
navigator.share({title: 'Example Page', url: 'https://example.com'});
```

but as far as I know Cordova also has a plugin, namely [cordova-share-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-share)

To use this plugin, simply call:

```
navigator.share(text,title,mimetype)
```

This is where I get confused. Both the built-in share API and the Cordova plugin have the same method `navigator.share()`. The expected parameters are different.

If I have installed the cordova share plugin and I call `navigator.share()` which code get executed? the plugin or the native share API?

It looks like one of my user is unable to share pictures because the call to `navigator.share()` fails silently. He has Android 8.1.0. All the other users seem to trigger the Cordova plugin when my app calls `navigator.share()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a pretty old plugin, created when `navigator.share` was not available in the browser.

The plugin clobbers `navigator.share`, so it will use the plugin implementation instead of the browser implementation.

Comment: ok. but if I remove the old plugin then navigator.share() will only be available on some Android versions. For example, on my device it complains that .share() is not a function

Comment: yeah, the plugin shouldn't clobber navigator.share, it should check if available, and if it isn't available then define it. You'll have to fork the plugin and make those changes or find another plugin that does it. There is this other plugin, but also redefines navigator.share without checking for existence https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin